# How can I overwrite a method's logic when using mockDomain in grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, dns

I would like to mock a domain with everything as usual (`mockDomain(Class)`), but I would like to overwrite one of the domain's methods (`beforeDelete` to be specific) with custom logic just for that one unit test.

**How can this be achieved?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the beforeDelete method on your domain class using Groovy metaClass.

Domain class:

```
class Person {
  String name
  boolean deleted

  def beforeDelete() {
    println "Deleting Person ${id}"
    deleted = true
    return false
  }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
void testBeforeDelete() {
    mockDomain(Person)
    def p = new Person(name:"test")
    p.save()
    assertEquals false, p.deleted
    p.delete()
    assertEquals true, p.deleted
}
```

--Output from testBeforeDelete--

Deleting Person 1

```
void testBeforeDeleteOverrideBeforeDelete() {
    mockDomain(Person)
    Person.metaClass.'static'.beforeDelete = {println 'Do not touch me'}
    def p = new Person(name:"test")
    p.save()
    assertEquals false, p.deleted
    p.delete()
    assertEquals true, p.deleted
}
```

--Output from testBeforeDeleteOverrideBeforeDelete--

Do not touch me

Comment: Great! Thanks, David. Could you tell me what the 'static' means/does in this context?

Comment: [Groovy Docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses#JN3525-MetaClasses-ExpandoMetaClass) In the example above we are using ExpandoMetaClass to add/override a static method on the Person class.

Answer (score 1):

Mock the domain class with `mockDomain` as usual, then mock the `beforeDelete` closure with `mockFor` in that one specific unit test.  For example:

```
void testDelete() {
    mockDomain(MyDomainClass)
    def myDomainClassControl = mockFor(MyDomainClass)
    myDomainClassControl.demand.beforeDelete(1..1) { -> println "hello world" }

    ... // test delete

    myDomainClassControl.verify()
}
```

Comment: How do I get an instance of the domain class? When I do **def md = new MyDomainClass()** and later on a **md.save()**, the test still runs the **original beforeDelete()**. If, on the other hand, I do **def md = myDomainClassControll.createMock()** then md.save() causes **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch**

Comment: The **argument type mismatch** seems to only vanish *when I remove* the **mockDomain(MyDomainClass)** - but then I receive **junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: verify[2]: expected 1..1 call(s) to 'beforeDelete' but was called 0 time(s).**

Comment: Ok, `beforeDelete` events seem to not get fired in unit tests under grails 1.3.7.  As an alternative, I'd suggest converting the test to an integration test.

Comment: I'm converting _from_ integration in order to reduce the amount of tests there :)