# How can I correctly move grails unit-test helper methods into a seperate file?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, dry, helper

I have some often-used helper methods for unit tests put into a seperate file. The idea is to, for example, allow my XYZTests.groovy to call TestHelper.getUserObject() in order to get a fully initialized instance of User.

Now the problem is, that there's a `springSecurityService.encodePassword(pw)` being called in the User's `beforeInsert()` which always fails as there's *no mock for springSecurityService* in TestHelper.groovy.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object
```

In **User.groovy**:

```
def beforeInsert() {
    // ...
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(pw)
    // ...
}
```

*Note: I would like to avoid any mocking **in** TestHelper.groovy in order to use it's methods in integration tests too.*

In spite of that, *even if* I try to call a `mockFor()` anywhere in the TestHelper.groovy, I get an MME:

```
No signature of method: static myproject.TestHelper.mockFor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class, java.lang.Boolean) values: [class grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService, true]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static myproject.TestHelper.mockFor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class, java.lang.Boolean) values: [class grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService, true]
    at myproject.TestHelper.mockSpringSecurityService(TestHelper.groovy:59)
    at myproject.TestHelper$mockSpringSecurityService.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.TestHelper.getUserObject(TestHelper.groovy:47)
    at myproject.TestHelper$getUserObject.call(Unknown Source)
    at myproject.UserTests.setUp(UserTests.groovy:26)
```

**Note:** I currently mock the `springSecurityService.encodePassword` like this:

```
// in UserTests.groovy
protected void setUp() {
    // mockDomain(...) and such here

    def u = TestHelper.getUserObject("Pummel")
    u.springSecurityService = mockSpringSecurityService()
    assert u.save()
}
private mockSpringSecurityService() {
    def ssService = mockFor(SpringSecurityService,true)
    ssService.metaClass.encodePassword() { password ->
        "08a2d3c63bf9fc88276d97a9e8df5f841fd772724ad10f119f7e516f228b74c6"
    }

    ssService
}
```

1. **Any ideas on how I may be able to use the helper class while leaving all mocking in the unit tests only?**
2. **Where would I best place the TestHelper.groovy file for using it in integration AND unit tests?**

*Note that everything is working perfectly fine when I move all helpers into UserTests.groovy directly!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this is to **refrain** from calling any `user.save()` in the **TestHelper.groovy**.

This makes sense, as for many (unit) tests a persisted (saved) instance is unnecessary anyways.

On the other hand many cases actually **require** an unsaved intance. (In order to test certain effects of the `.save()` itself, for example)

A working example **for integration tests** would be:

```
def user = TestHelper.getUserObject()
user.save()
```

For a **unit tests:**

```
def user = TestHelper.getUserObject()
user.springSecurityService = new SpringSecurityService() // or the described mock accordingly
user.save()
```

*This keeps any mocks out of TestHelper.groovy*

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `TestHelper` you can use Groovy [ExpandoMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses) metaClass.static to slap a mock closure for encodePassword on SpringSecurityService:

   ```
   SpringSecurityService.metaClass.'static'.encodePassword = {'08a2d3c63bf9fc88276d97a9e8df5f841fd772724ad10f119f7e516f228b74c6'}
   ```
2. I would stick this class in a test package under src/groovy

Comment: Thanks for your response, David. I had follow that approach for some other mocks (as you suggested in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887177/how-can-i-overwrite-a-methods-logic-when-using-mockdomain-in-grails)), but apparantly it's having trouble in this case. Maybe because it's a service instead of a domain? I've just tried `User.metaClass.'static'.beforeInsert = { '' }`, which works, but I'd rather mock the `encodePassword` only. Also note that there's the described problem when calling mockFor(). Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I suspect the problem as follows: The dependency injection of `def springSecurityService` in **User.groovy** doesn't happen (as there is no DI in unit tests). When calling `springSecurityService.encodePassword(pw)`, `springSecurityService` is just seen as a normal, **uninitialized** property, which results in `null.encodePassword(pw)` being called. It's considered a property of the instance instead of a static method of a class.

Comment: This is a bit nit-picky of me, but I try to avoid calling service methods from my Domain classes as it violates my "tiers." My approach would be to have a UserService that encodes the password before calling User.save().

Comment: You mean calling the service manually before any `user.save()`? Ain't that a little error-prone?